# Prevent last css animation from hiding

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have a CSS animation I found online to loop through a website headline, but at the moment, when the last headline appears, it also hides, meaning there is no headline visible at the end.

What I've spent the last hour trying to work out, is how can I have the css animation work like I do right now, except when the last headline appears, instead of sliding out and hiding, it just stays there...

Here is what I have:

```css
.rw-sentence {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.rw-sentence span {
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.rw-words {
  display: inline;
}

.rw-words-1 span {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
  animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .rw-sentence {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .rw-sentence {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="h2 homeTitle rw-words rw-words-1">
  <span>First headline.</span>
  <span>Second headline.</span>
  <span>Third headline.</span>
  <span>Fourth headline.</span>
  <span>Fifth headline.</span>
  <span>My final headline...</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it i thinks it help full

```css
.rw-sentence {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.rw-sentence span {
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.rw-words {
  display: inline;
}
.rw-words-1 span:last-child {
      -webkit-animation: rotateend 8s 1 forwards 6s;
      -ms-animation: rotateend 8s 1 forwards 6s;
      animation: rotateend 8s 1 forwards 6s;
}
@keyframes rotateend {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      2% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
        transform: translateY(-30px);
      }
      5% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      17% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      100% {opacity: 1}
  }
.rw-words-1 span {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
  animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
  animation-delay: 7.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  
  
  
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .rw-sentence {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .rw-sentence {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="h2 homeTitle rw-words rw-words-1">
  <span>First headline.</span>
  <span>Second headline.</span>
  <span>Third headline.</span>
  <span>Fourth headline.</span>
  <span>Fifth headline.</span>
  <span>My final headline...</span>
</span>
```

i have  add some css

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `animation` for the *last* `span` in the container like this:

```
.rw-words-1 span:not(:last-child) {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
  animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
}

.rw-words-1 span:last-child {
   position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: showWord 8s linear;
  -ms-animation: showWord 8s linear;
  animation: showWord 8s linear;
}
```

and the `keyframe` animation something like this:

```
@keyframes showWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  95% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

See a demo below - I guess you can take it forward from this point:

```css
.rw-words {
  display: inline;
}

.rw-words-1 span:not(:last-child) {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
  -ms-animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
  animation: rotateWord 7.5s linear;
}

.rw-words-1 span:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: showWord 8s linear;
  -ms-animation: showWord 8s linear;
  animation: showWord 8s linear;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 1.5s;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 4.5s;
  animation-delay: 4.5s;
}

.rw-words-1 span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  2% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes showWord {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  95% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="h2 homeTitle rw-words rw-words-1">
  <span>First headline.</span>
  <span>Second headline.</span>
  <span>Third headline.</span>
  <span>Fourth headline.</span>
  <span>Fifth headline.</span>
  <span>My final headline...</span>
</span>
```

Comment: it's a decent solution but the transition from the before last to the last headline is not quite as seamless as the answer I marked as correct...

Comment: Yeah, that's cool. I didn't look at perfecting the transition, but wanted to show you the way, so that you can take it forward. Also upvote if the answer helped you, thanks! :)